# How to interpret P(X>x) in a Poisson distribution question

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> Cotton cloth is sold from long rolls of cloth. The number of flaws on a randomly chosen piece of cloth of length $a$ meters has a Poisson distribution with mean $0.8a$. The random variable $X$ is the length of cloth, in metres, between two successive flaws. For $x \ge 0$, find $P(X>x).$
>
> Source : Cambridge A-level Further Mathematics 9231_s15_qp_21 Question 9

### My work

$W:$  number of flaws

Rate of flaws = 0.8 flaws per metre

$W \sim Poisson(0.8)$

$X:$ distance between 2 successive flaws

$X$ is exponentially distributed.

PDF of X : $f(w)=0.8e^{-0.8w}$ for $w \ge 0$

$P(X>x)=\int^{\infty}_x 0.8e^{-0.8w}dw=e^{-0.8x}$

---

In the mark scheme of this question it is simply written :

> $P(X>x)= P($zero flaws in $x$ m$)=P_0(0.8x)=e^{-0.8x}$

I don't understand why $P(X>x)=$ $P($zero flaws in $x$ m$)$

Comment: You're looking for the connection between the Poisson distribution and the exponential distribution. The Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$ gives the number of independent exponential($\lambda$) distributed events that occur in time $t$.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2092/356619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively when you defined the variable $X$ you did not specified if it was between the time of the second and third flaw, third and fourth,... . Because it does not affect the distribution of $X$ (see lack of memory for exponential distributions). Therefore when you look at the event ''$X>x$'' you just want to be zero flaw in x metters.
.